# React Same Component Communication

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good Morning,

I'm creating an react app, this application will have four "sides" and each side can have different values so I mapped the same component 4 times:

```
:[...Array(item)].map((data) =>
          <Side 
           key={ data }
           Style='wall-holder' 
           InputClass='input-height' 
           />
      )
 }
```

So each Side could work  as its own thing, in each side  the user can input an specific value using the inputs that exists in the Side component:

```
Side Component= input= 1, input =2;
Side Component= input=3, input =5;
Side Component= input=3, input =5;
Side Component= input=3, input =5;
```

note: is only one component Side, I just mapped it 4 time so i could reuse it

Now I want to be able to get all of those inputs in an array or object so I can add all of the input values, however when I try to send it to a global state with the api context, it only keeps the last added value, I understand why is this happening(kinda), but I dont know yet how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a state in your parent component like below. use index to update each input state of Side components.

```
import {useState} from "react";

const ParentComp = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({});
    
    return [...Array(item)].map((data, dataIndex) =>
          <Side 
           key={ data }
           Style='wall-holder' 
           InputClass='input-height' 
           setState={setState}
           dataIndex={dataIndex}
           />
      )
 }
```

In your `Side` component.

```
<input
    onChange={e =>
        props.setState(prevState => {
            return { ...prevState, [props.dataIndex]: e.target.value };
        })
    }
/>;
```

Comment: @Ruan Miguel, Hope this helps!